# what is the meaning of this Logical operators combination in C

Tags: c, pointers, embedded, logic

i know that -> is a pointer |= is OR.
what is the logical meaning of such line?

TIMER0->ROUTELOC0 |= TIMER_ROUTELOC0_CC0LOC_LOC15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're ORing in (setting) a value to a register. Your processor has a TIMER0 with a register ROUTELOC0. It likely has a bit that is "CC0LOC_LOC15"

I recommend looking at the data sheet for your processor to figure out what that means specifically.

Comment: This is my code, Why Are we using OR for Setting route to Location?

// Set route to Location 15 and enable
  // TIM0_CC0 #15 is PC10
  TIMER0->ROUTELOC0 |=  TIMER_ROUTELOC0_CC0LOC_LOC15;

  TIMER0->ROUTEPEN |= TIMER_ROUTEPEN_CC0PEN;

Comment: You use OR because you don't want to mess with any of the other bits in the register. If you were just setting it (`TIMER0->ROUTELOC0 = TIMER_ROUTELOC0_CC0LOC_LOC15;`), you'd clear all the other bits in the register inadvertently. As to why you're setting it, I don't know what processor you're using, so I can't tell you that.

Answer (score 1):

|= does not mean OR. | means OR.

|= is similar to +=, that is

A |= B is the equivalent of A = A | B

So to answer your question:
It looks like `TIMER0` is a structure with a member `ROUTELOC0`. The above expression is setting the `ROUTELOC0` as the result when `ROUTELOC0` is ORed with `TIMER_ROUTELOC0_CC0LOC_LOC15`

Answer (score 0):

The `->` is the *structure dereference operator*, and `|=` is the *bitwise OR assignment* operator (compound assignment).

The compound assignment:

```
x |= y ;
```

is equavilent to:

```
x = x | y ;
```

It is important here to understand that bitwise-OR (`|`) is distinct from boolean-OR (`||`).  It is used here to set specific bits in `x` leaving other bits unset.

For example, to set the two least significant bits of `x` to 1:

```
    x: 10100000
    y: 00000011
      ---------
  x|y: 10100011
```