# How does the following C operators combined

Tags: c, embedded, operators

For EFR32FG14P231F256M32 I have the following combination of C operators. with the descrition shown bellow.I am having trouble matching the description to the code.

- `->` is a pointer. We have pointing directions on both sides?
- `|` is bitwise-OR
- `.DOUT` I think means taking the `DOUT` member from the following `P[gpioPortC]` cell,

but regrading  | (1 << 5); I am having problem understand.

What is the logical meaning of such C operator combinations in single line?

The following code configures pin 5 from Port C as a digital input with pull-up and filter. The MODE5 bitfield from GPIO_PC_MODEL
register must be set to 0b0011, and the correspondent bit in the GPIO_PC_DOUT register must also be set to 1 to determine the pull
direction. A pin can be configured either by using the functions available in the emlib or through a direct register write:

```
GPIO->P[gpioPortC ].DOUT = GPIO->P[gpioPortC ].DOUT | (1 << 5); //Input enabled with pull up and filter
GPIO->P[gpioPortC ].MODEL = (GPIO->P[gpioPortC ].MODEL & ~_GPIO_P_MODEL_MODE5_MASK) |
GPIO_P_MODEL_MODE5_INPUTPULLFILTER;
```

Comment: As I explained to you at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61957648/what-is-the-meaning-of-this-logical-operators-combination-in-c `->` is not a pointer.  It is a _structire dereference_; it left-hand operand _is_ a pointer.  It is generally better not to explain what you think you know, because it is a) irrelevant, and b) you may be wrong.  Just ask you question and let others more accurately explain whet the code does.

Comment: I get the impression that you are trying to learn C from staring at other peoples code and posting questions of SO.  If the code was written with the aim of teaching and is of reputable quality, that is fine, but with arbitrary  "production" code, as a novice you have no way to determining the complexity or quality of the code.  It is generally a poor way to learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`1 << 5` is a constant expression having the binary value `0b100000`.  You could simply replace it with the literal constant value 0x20 or 32, however the purpose of the expression is to create a *bit mask* with bit-5 set.

It is expressed in this manner because:

- it documents intent without having to write a comment.  It is self-documenting code - it says to the reader *"this is a mask for bit 5"*,
- when coding it, it is less error prone to let the compiler calculate the constant value of a bit 5 mask.

So:

```
x = x | ( 1 << 5) ;
```

sets bit 5 of the variable (or in this case *register*) `x`.  With respect to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61957648/what-is-the-meaning-of-this-logical-operators-combination-in-c), it can also be expressed as:

```
x |= (1 <<5) ;
```

With respec to your secondary question:

> - `->` *is a pointer. We have pointing directions on both sides?*

I am not clear what you are asking, `->` but is not a pointer; it is the *structure dereference* operator; its left-hand operand is a pointer, and its right hand operator is a member of the structure to which the left-hand is a pointer *to* (which may or may not be a pointer.

And before you ask, the second line of your fragment, that has teh *form*:

```
x = x & ~mask ;
```

Sets all the bits of `x` that are 1 in `mask` to zero.  It is the revers of the previous idiom:

```
 x &= ~mask ;  // Clear mask bits
 x &= mask ;   // Set mask pits
```

In your particular example you have a more complex expression:

```
GPIO->P[gpioPortC].DOUT | (1 << 5)
```

Here you need to understand the concept of *[operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence)*. `->` has precedence over `|`, so the `GPIO->P[gpioPortC].DOUT` sub expression is evaluatet first so that the `| (1 << 5);` applies to the `DOUT` member of the referenced structure.  Note that `[]` is also an operator, (with higher precedence than `->`.  So that in the general form:

```
x | y ;
```

...

```
x =  GPIO->P[gpioPortC].DOUT 
y = (1 << 5)
```

Answer (score 1):

The << operator means "shift bits left", and it works as follows:

```
a << b
```

shifts the bits in *a*, *b* places to the left.
to answer your question directly, 1 << 5 moves the bits in 0x01 5 times to the left, resulting in 0x20, which is 32 in decimal notation. This has the effect of multiplying a number by 2 n times (n=5 in your case). The resultant value is ORed with the value in DOUT, and then stored in DOUT itself.

EDIT:
To answer the question OP added in the comments -

What happens in the assignments in your code is similar to this: `x = x + 5`.

The `->` operator is shorthand for `(*obj).field`. The first line in your code instructs the following:

1. Take the value within `GPIO->P[gpioPortC].DOUT` and OR it with `0x10`.
2. Assign the result to `GPIO->P[gpioPortC].DOUT`.

The second line does a pretty similar operation, only instead of preforming a bitwise OR and storing it in the same field, it preforms a bitwise AND of the field with a negated form of some predefined value, and then preforms a bitwise OR of the result with another predefined value, and then stores it within that field.

It is important to understand that simply using the `->` operator on an object does nothing except allowing you to access the fields stored within this object (which themselves might be pointers to other locations in memory, or primitive variables).

Comment: Hello,What about the pointing -> to and array with object orient.
As if its saying to point  GPIO on both sides .on left side it says to point to P[gpioPortC ].DOUT on the other side it says to point at some bit wise or.

isnt it a confilct and we should have -> only on one side?

Comment: @rocko445 : You have accepted this answer which indicates it is complete as far as you are concerned, but you then comment asking for more.  If it does not answer your question fully, don't accept it (yet).  Other's who might answer more fully might not take the time if it appears there is an acceptable answer already, and here Eviatar might not even be motivated to expand his answer in response to your comment now it is accepted in any case. If you accept an answer within minutes of posting a question, you'll only see answers from similar time-zones to yours; you might give it 24 hours.